# ldapjs authentication error when binding to LDAP server

Tags: javascript, node.js, ldap

I have issue on connecting to LDAP server using **ldapjs** lib. For some reason I cannot bind to ldap server using my credentials:

```
var ldap = require('ldapjs');

function authDN(dn, password, cb) {
    var client = ldap.createClient({url: 'ldaps://myserver:1234'});

    client.bind(dn, password, function (err) {
        client.unbind();
        cb(err === null, err);
    });
}


function output(res, err) {
    if (res) {
        console.log('success');
    } else {
        console.log('failure' + err.message);
    }
}

// should print "success"
authDN('CN=J33nn,OU=Members,DC=domains', 'password', output);
// should print "failure"
authDN('cn=user', 'badpasswd', output);
```

To be perfectly sure I've checked my **dn** in LDAP and tested binding to LDAP using python script and it worked.

Any ideas what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the username format is wrong or your DN is not correct, instead of

```
CN=J33nn,OU=Members,DC=domains
```

Try using:

```
J33nn@company.domain.com
```

Or you should use a [LDAP exlorer tool](http://ldaptool.sourceforge.net/) to check **your real/correct DN name** by bind to your LDAP server.